# How to Make GridLayout Background Transparent?

Tags: android, css, xml, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I am implementing GridLayout in a recycler view with Images loading from the drawable folder.

[Image Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVbx2.jpg)

So as you can see , the background is white and I want to make it Transparent, 
My XML code for this layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Abcd"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have tried a lot of things that such as :-

- Making Recycler View's alpha as 0
- Card View's Alpha as 0
- Setting Card Background Color to Transparent and setting Max Elevation to 0 so as to reduce the shadow

Still, I am not able to get the transparent Background. Can anyone suggest a new way?

Also , **the Images used are Vector Images with transparent background.**

**UPDATE**

It works now ,Thanks to @Adley
I just had to remove the card layout that i was using and cast into a normal relative layout

Comment: You want the full transparet background? Cause if yes, you can set cardview bg color same of the layout background

Comment: Yes , I just want the green images to be there and nothing else . And my layout color is white so even if I set my card view color to be white , the borders between two grid items make it easily distinguishable as is displayed in the screenshot

Comment: Oh, I get it. But why use card view if you don't want cardView? Maybe you can change this cardview for [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Comment: Oh yes , that was foolish of me . 
It works perfectly now . 
Thank You so much

Comment: Glad to hear this :). You're welcome!

Comment: Try setOpaque(false) for layout and its children.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

Try adding `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"`
 to your root view (CardView).

Comment: Did that too when I was setting card view's color to transparent. Didnt work

Comment: We will need some more information to be able to help you. Can you put a screenshot of what you have with the layout as from the question?

Comment: The link is there in the description . Sadly the Website doesn't let me imbedd the screenshot as my reputation is less than 10

Comment: Well, I have already tried this as I have already  mentioned in the question description .

Comment: I'm out of ideas... All I can think of is to clean/rebuild your project (without android:background="#000" )  and hoping for the best. Good luck!

Comment: Alright , I did that again.  Same story. Anyhow thanks for your suggestions mate